# Unable to select date values in views filter(exposed grouped filter) implemented through Datepicker module on a Date Type form field

Tags: views, datetime

### Pre-requisite knowledge:

1. I have a view - *All Albums* to list all content of *Album*
   content-type.
2. I have a field in *Album* content-type - **Release Date** of type
   Date.
3. I use [Datepicke](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker)r module (enabled Datepicker block and Datepicker
   Views as well) in the Views Filter handler in Date filters (filter
   on Release Date field in this case).
4. In View Edit overlay for *All Albums* View, I created a new filter
   on *Content: Release Date*.
5. Then, under *Configure extra settings for filter criterion...*, set
   *Date selection form element* to *Select* and *Filter granularity* to *Year* (these extra settings are being implemented)
6. Then, under *Configure filter criterion*, exposed this filter to
   visitors and selected *Grouped filters*.

[image: actual]

### Problem Statement

I expected something like this to appear under *Value column*:
[image: ideal]

But I am not getting it!
I guess this is a bug in [Datepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker) module but can't say for sure.
Moreover, I want to expose this date value under *Value column* to site-user/visitor; how to do that?